# How can I remove the rest of the commas when the output is displayed?

Tags: javascript

I have found that when using an array with child elements or like a 2d array the .join function only removes the commas when displayed from the top elements of the array.

How can I remove all of the commas when displaying the array?

I used `"\n"` which worked great for what I want but for the rest, I don't want any commas so I want to replace them with `""`.

```js
function gameloop(){

    var mainArray = [];
    var mapSizeX = 10;
    var mapSizeY = 10;
  

    function nl(){topbody.innerText += "\n";}
    function fill2DimensionsmainArrayay(mainArray, mapSizeX, mapSizeY){
        for (var i = 0; i < mapSizeX; i++) {
            mainArray.push([0])
            
            for (var j = 0; j < mapSizeY; j++) {
                mainArray[i][j] = 0;
            }
        }
    }

   


    fill2DimensionsmainArrayay(mainArray, mapSizeX, mapSizeY);
 
    topbody.innerText += mainArray.join("\n");



}

gameloop();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Hello</title>
</head>
<body>
<section id="topbody"></section>
<script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you have commas in between the zeroes is because you have a two-dimensional array and the inner arrays are being serialised (their `toString()` method is being called). When arrays are serialised their elements are delimited with commas. See below for example demonstrating this:

```js
console.log([1, 2, 3].toString())

// calls toString() behind the scenes
document.body.innerHTML = "serialised value: " + [1, 2, 3]
```

To remove the commas, map over the array and join each inner array's elements by an empty string. Then join the result of that map with newlines. Like so:

```js
const mainArray = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6]]
const text = mainArray
  .map(arr => arr.join(""))
  .join("\n")
document.body.innerText = text
```

Full example:

```js
function gameloop(){
    var mainArray = [];
    var mapSizeX = 10;
    var mapSizeY = 10;
  
    function nl(){topbody.innerText += "\n";}
    function fill2DimensionsmainArrayay(mainArray, mapSizeX, mapSizeY){
        for (var i = 0; i < mapSizeX; i++) {
            mainArray.push([0])
        
            for (var j = 0; j < mapSizeY; j++) {
                mainArray[i][j] = 0;
            }
        }
    }

    fill2DimensionsmainArrayay(mainArray, mapSizeX, mapSizeY);

    topbody.innerText += mainArray.map(arr => arr.join("")).join("\n");
}

gameloop();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Hello</title>
</head>
<body>
<section id="topbody"></section>
<script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```